# Stop multiple async calls from client Node JS Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a single page app that gets a list of objects from an node js server.  However if the user selects the first item in the list before the rest of the related objects are loaded it needs to cancel the request.  I can cancel the request on the client side (angular) but don't see how to cancel a request on an already started call in node !

The code below is the method i use to call the node api with the ability to cancel that request on the client side.

```
getDiscovery : function(ids) {
      var Ids = [],
        apiUrl = '/api/Something/ids',
        self = this,
        deferredAbort = $q.defer();

      // Initiate the AJAX request.
      var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: apiUrl,
        params: {
          ids: JSON.stringify(ids) 
        },
        timeout: deferredAbort.promise
      });

      var promise = request.then(
        function(response) {
        return(response.data);
        },
        function(response) {
          return($q.reject( "Something went wrong" ));
        }
      );

      promise.abort = function() {
        deferredAbort.resolve();
      };

      promise.finally(
        function() {
          console.info( "Cleaning up object references." );
          promise.abort = angular.noop;
          deferredAbort = request = promise = null;
        }
      );

      return(promise);
```

}

This is the method on the node api which needs to be cancelled

```
exports.getItemsDiscovery = function(req, res){
var Items = JSON.parse(req.query.ids);


async.each(Items,
    function(Item, callback){
        method.getSomething(Item.Id, function(data){
            console.log('Got data for', item.Id);
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(err) {
        return res.send(Items);
});
};
```

The route is

app.get('/api/ids', something.getItemsDiscovery);

Any help would be much appreciated

Rob

Comment: If you've solved the problem of cancelling the request on the client, then why not simply ignore the server's response?

Comment: I thought that but it seems to slow down node as it's potentially fired off 200+ requests to a third party api

Comment: It sounds as though you have a more fundamental optimisation problem to deal with on your server! Without knowing why your server is issuing that many requests it's impossible to suggest remedies, but then I guess that's a whole other problem (and question).

Comment: No it's not the amount of requests, I have to make a crazy call to an external api to build a certain object that is needed for later filtering of initial results